# How to read a file starting from a specific line number using Scanner?

Tags: file, go, readfile

I am new to Go and I am trying to write a simple script that reads a file line by line. I also want to save the progress (i.e. the last line number that was read) on the filesystem somewhere so that if the same file was given as the input to the script again, it starts reading the file from the line where it left off. Following is what I have started off with.

```
package main

// Package Imports
import (
    "bufio"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

// Variable Declaration
var (
    ConfigFile = flag.String("configfile", "../config.json", "Path to json configuration file.")
)

// The main function that reads the file and parses the log entries
func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    settings := NewConfig(*ConfigFile)

    inputFile, err := os.Open(settings.Source)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer inputFile.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(inputFile)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
    }

    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

// Saves the current progress
func SaveProgress() {

}

// Get the line count from the progress to make sure
func GetCounter() {

}
```

I could not find any methods that deals with line numbers in the scanner package. I know I can declare an integer say `counter := 0` and increment it each time a line is read like `counter++`. But the next time how do I tell the scanner to start from a specific line? So for example if I read till line `30` the next time I run the script with the same input file, how can I make scanner to start reading from line `31`?

#### Update

One solution I can think of here is to use the counter as I stated above and use an if condition like the following.

```
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(inputFile)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        if counter > progress {
            fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
        }
    }
```

I am pretty sure something like this would work, but it is still going to loop over the lines that we have already read. Please suggest a better way.

Comment: There's no metadata in a file to indicate where "line 30" is. unless you store the byte offset somewhere, you need to read from the start every time.

Comment: @JimB Thanks for your response. Please check the update in the question, is that my best bet ? Are there any other packages available that are capable of doing this ?

Comment: Call `scanner.Scan()` 30 times of whatever your counter value is. If you think is too slow (which is doubtful for config file) store offset and use https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.ReadAt

Comment: How large are these files, i.e. are you reading in millions of lines? If you need to get the actual position, don't use a Scanner, use the lower lever methods on the bufio.Reader. You can get the position by comparing the file position with the number of buffered bytes.

Comment: @JimB yes, these are postfix log files that I am trying to read on a centralized logging server, so yeah they are pretty big.

Answer (score 29):

If you don't want to read but just skip the lines you read previously, you need to acquire the position where you left off.

The different solutions are presented in a form of a function which takes the input to read from and the start position (byte position) to start reading lines from, e.g.:

```
func solution(input io.ReadSeeker, start int64) error
```

A special [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) input is used which also implements [`io.Seeker`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Seeker), the common interface which allows skipping data without having to read them. [`*os.File`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File) implements this, so you are allowed to pass a `*File` to these functions. Good. The "merged" interface of both `io.Reader` and `io.Seeker` is [`io.ReadSeeker`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadSeeker).

If you want a *clean start* (to start reading from the beginning of the file), simply pass `start = 0`. If you want to *resume* a previous processing, pass the byte position where the last processing was stopped/aborted. This position is the value of the `pos` local variable in the functions (solutions) below.

All the examples below with their testing code can be found on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/eaWYAkxyLI).

### 1. With `bufio.Scanner`

[`bufio.Scanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner) does not maintain the position, but we can very easily extend it to maintain the position (the read bytes), so when we want to restart next, we can seek to this position.

In order to do this with minimal effort, we can use a new split function which splits the input into tokens (lines). We can use [`Scanner.Split()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner.Split) to set the splitter function (the logic to decide where are the boundaries of tokens/lines). The default split function is [`bufio.ScanLines()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#ScanLines).

Let's take a look at the split function declaration: [`bufio.SplitFunc`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#SplitFunc)

```
type SplitFunc func(data []byte, atEOF bool) (advance int, token []byte, err error)
```

It returns the number of bytes to advance: `advance`. Exactly what we need to maintain the file position. So we can create a new split function using the builtin `bufio.ScanLines()`, so we don't even have to implement its logic, just use the `advance` return value to maintain position:

```
func withScanner(input io.ReadSeeker, start int64) error {
    fmt.Println("--SCANNER, start:", start)
    if _, err := input.Seek(start, 0); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(input)

    pos := start
    scanLines := func(data []byte, atEOF bool) (advance int, token []byte, err error) {
        advance, token, err = bufio.ScanLines(data, atEOF)
        pos += int64(advance)
        return
    }
    scanner.Split(scanLines)

    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Printf("Pos: %d, Scanned: %s\n", pos, scanner.Text())
    }
    return scanner.Err()
}
```

### 2. With `bufio.Reader`

In this solution we use the [`bufio.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader) type instead of the `Scanner`. `bufio.Reader` already has a [`ReadBytes()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadBytes) method which is very similar to the "read a line" functionality if we pass the `'\n'` byte as the delimeter.

This solution is similar to JimB's, with the addition of handling all valid line terminator sequences and also stripping them off from the read line (it is very rare they are needed); in regular expression notation, it is `\r?\n`.

```
func withReader(input io.ReadSeeker, start int64) error {
    fmt.Println("--READER, start:", start)
    if _, err := input.Seek(start, 0); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    r := bufio.NewReader(input)
    pos := start
    for {
        data, err := r.ReadBytes('\n')
        pos += int64(len(data))
        if err == nil || err == io.EOF {
            if len(data) > 0 && data[len(data)-1] == '\n' {
                data = data[:len(data)-1]
            }
            if len(data) > 0 && data[len(data)-1] == '\r' {
                data = data[:len(data)-1]
            }
            fmt.Printf("Pos: %d, Read: %s\n", pos, data)
        }
        if err != nil {
            if err != io.EOF {
                return err
            }
            break
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

**Note:** If the content ends with an empty line (line terminator), this solution will process an empty line. If you don't want this, you can simply check it like this:

```
if len(data) != 0 {
    fmt.Printf("Pos: %d, Read: %s\n", pos, data)
} else {
    // Last line is empty, omit it
}
```

### Testing the solutions:

Testing code will simply use the content `"first\r\nsecond\nthird\nfourth"` which contains multiple lines with varying line terminating. We will use [`strings.NewReader()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#NewReader) to obtain an `io.ReadSeeker` whose source is a `string`.

Test code first calls `withScanner()` and `withReader()` passing `0` start position: a *clean start*. In the next round we will pass a start position of `start = 14` which is the position of the 3. line, so we won't see the first 2 lines processed (printed): *resume* simulation.

```
func main() {
    const content = "first\r\nsecond\nthird\nfourth"

    if err := withScanner(strings.NewReader(content), 0); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Scanner error:", err)
    }
    if err := withReader(strings.NewReader(content), 0); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Reader error:", err)
    }

    if err := withScanner(strings.NewReader(content), 14); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Scanner error:", err)
    }
    if err := withReader(strings.NewReader(content), 14); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Reader error:", err)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
--SCANNER, start: 0
Pos: 7, Scanned: first
Pos: 14, Scanned: second
Pos: 20, Scanned: third
Pos: 26, Scanned: fourth
--READER, start: 0
Pos: 7, Read: first
Pos: 14, Read: second
Pos: 20, Read: third
Pos: 26, Read: fourth
--SCANNER, start: 14
Pos: 20, Scanned: third
Pos: 26, Scanned: fourth
--READER, start: 14
Pos: 20, Read: third
Pos: 26, Read: fourth
```

Try the solutions and testing code on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/eaWYAkxyLI).

Comment: Amazing answer and explanation. Thanks @icza

Comment: Your regexp for multiple line ending types is wrong. `\r\n`, `\r` and `\n` are all valid line endings. The correct regexp would be `/(\r\n|\r|\n)/`

Comment: @caffinatedmonkey [`bufio.ScanLines()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#ScanLines) also mentions / uses `\r?\n`.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using a `Scanner`, use a [`bufio.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader), specifically the `ReadBytes` or `ReadString` methods. This way you can read up to each line termination, and still receive the full line with line endings.

```
r := bufio.NewReader(inputFile)

var line []byte
fPos := 0 // or saved position

for i := 1; ; i++ {
    line, err = r.ReadBytes('\n')
    fmt.Printf("[line:%d pos:%d] %q\n", i, fPos, line)

    if err != nil {
        break
    }
    fPos += len(line)
}

if err != io.EOF {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

You can store the combination of file position and line number however you choose, and the next time you start, you use `inputFile.Seek(fPos, os.SEEK_SET)` to move to where you left off.

Comment: Amazing, Thanks. I am gonna try this and accept your answer.

Comment: @Amyth: i just occurred to me that I quickly wrote that example from a combination of 2 other pieces, and you don't really need the `Seek` call to get the position when using the `bufio.Reader`, just add up the bytes read (this will save a lot of syscalls too)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use Scanner you have go trough the begging of the file till you find `GetCounter()` end-line symbols.

```
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(inputFile)
// context line above

// skip first GetCounter() lines
for i := 0; i < GetCounter(); i++ {
    scanner.Scan()
}

// context line below
for scanner.Scan() {
    fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
}
```

Alternatively you could store **offset** instead of line number in the counter but remember that **termination token is stripped** when using Scanner and for new line the token is `\r?\n` (regexp notation) so it isn't clear if you should add 1 or 2 to the text length:

```
// Not clear how to store offset unless custom SplitFunc provided
inputFile.Seek(GetCounter(), 0)
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(inputFile)
```

So it is better to use previous solution or not using Scanner at all.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of words in the other answers, and they're not really reusable code so here's a re-usable function that seeks to the given line number & returns it and the offset where the line starts. [play.golang](https://play.golang.org/p/5tQW_Lk46Wh)

```
func SeekToLine(r io.Reader, lineNo int) (line []byte, offset int, err error) {
    s := bufio.NewScanner(r)

    var pos int

    s.Split(func(data []byte, atEof bool) (advance int, token []byte, err error) {
        advance, token, err = bufio.ScanLines(data, atEof)
        pos += advance
        return advance, token, err
    })

    for i := 0; i < lineNo; i++ {
        offset = pos

        if !s.Scan() {
            return nil, 0, io.EOF
        }
    }

    return s.Bytes(), pos, nil
}
```